# Write on linux chardevice in java

Tags: java, linux, device

i'm trying to read and write on a char device in ubuntu but when i create the outputstream i get this exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/usb/legousbtower0 (Device or resource busy)

This is my code:

```
myInputStream = new FileInputStream("/dev/usb/legousbtower0");
myOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/dev/usb/legousbtower0");
```

The inputstream works and i can write to the device using the terminal

> echo test > /dev/usb/legousbtower0

I try to detect what is using the device using fuser but nothing results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the device as an `InputStream`, it is marked as open by the operating system. Since only one program should access the device at a time, the second `open` will fail. You need to open the device in read-write mode, probably using the 
[RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Comment: Thank you! I used RandomAccessFile and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried opening it with append = true?

```
myOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/dev/usb/legousbtower0", true);
```

Comment: yea it was mostly a guess, I didn't really think it would.